# Where to download OpenCv contrib for windows?

Tags: opencv, opencv-contrib

OpenCv release in the official page, https://opencv.org/releases.html does not provide contrib release. For Android, contrib can be found https://pullrequest.opencv.org/buildbot/builders/3_4-contrib_pack-contrib-android. But where can I find windows OpenCv contrib?

Comment: You have to compile it yourself. Check the github repo.

Comment: So if you need some functionality from contrib packages, you must compile complete opencv yourself. There is no simple way to compile only some contrib package[s] if you have downloaded a pre-built opencv library. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the zip file for OpenCV Contrib from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)

The installation instructions from [this blog](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-windows/) worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tags)

And use [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) to make opencv_contrib's include, dll, lib directory

I don't know if it's a good explanation, here are [installation instruction](https://seokhan.tistory.com/entry/%EA%B8%B0%EC%A1%B4-OpenCV-%ED%8F%B4%EB%8D%94%EC%97%90-contribextra-modules-%EC%B6%94%EA%B0%80%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0)